# I believe I'm getting downvoted for no good reason. What can I do about this?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I have a couple of questions that are, IMHO, being downvoted with no good reason. Is there anything I can do to counter this?

Comment: Nope. Downvotes happen, don't worry about it. If there are downvotes on a series of your posts, then the automatic serial-vote script will revert them.

Comment: It might be reversed by the serial vote reversal script that runs daily, if the voting is detected as malicious.  Beyond that your best bet is to ignore it.

Comment: If you are, however, receiving multiple downvotes on your questions (like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483536/store-non-nul-terminated-c-string-constant-in-c)) you may want to listen to the feedback given in the comments. You could also review [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to better communicate what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have been listening to the comments and have responded to their concerns.  What is the reason for the down vote on this question?

Comment: Please read the Meta FAQ. Downvotes here are sometimes a bit different. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @JoshCaswell Serial downvoting is not the case here. The dupe does not seem to apply.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be ruled out by anything in the question, @Bart.

Comment: It is ruled out by the voting seen within the OP's profile @JoshCaswell

Comment: What do you mean by ruled out?  What is being ruled out?

Comment: @Adrian Your meta question was most likely downvoted due to lack of research.  This is a very frequently asked question that is highly discoverable.  You could have easily answered this question yourself with a simple meta search or looking at the "related" questions provided to you before you posted your question.  It has nothing to do with the differences in voting that is described in Bart's link.

Comment: @Servy The disagreement in this case might apply to the statement that the downvotes were for "no good reason". But that's of course speculation.

Comment: @Bart True enough; I imagine there's some combination of the two at this point.

Comment: @Servy: I had looked at the related questions but they didn't seem to give any that were related.  Every forum has some learning curve.  This one is no different.

Comment: @Adrian: Well, except that it isn't a forum, it's a Q+A site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I believe I'm getting downvoted for no good reason. What can I do about this?

### Nothing.

Well actually you can **learn from it**.

If you're talking about Meta, don't forget that [down-votes are different here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

If you're talking about Stack Overflow, you're still new around here have you looked at all the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to make sure you're not doing anything the wrong way? The community is pretty picky and expect you to know how to ask your questions considering all the tools you have before posting.

If we take a quick look at [one of your question that got downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487260/is-it-possible-to-write-static-assembly-data-in-c-struct).

What's the question there? You said "hey this doesn't work". Doesn't fit the Q&A standards **at all**.

Anyway, don't take downvotes too seriously. Everyone will collect some on the way. Especially when you post your first questions.

Comment: I didn't say that, but I get your point.  I got curt with one of the users, which wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your [most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483536/store-non-nul-terminated-c-string-constant-in-c) received a series of downvotes probably because of the "don't do this, no seriously, do not" vibe hanging around it. The [other downvoted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487260/is-it-possible-to-write-static-assembly-data-in-c-struct) probably got downvoted for lack of detail. There isn't a lot you can do other than try and heed the comments, or ignore the downvotes all together. Like @MarijnPieters commented, if someone is maliciously downvoting you, SO will detect this and revert those downvotes.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by `do do this, no seriousl do not`?  I didn't see any of that.

Comment: You start your own question with ""DON'T DO THIS as it is really bad"." and half the comments say just that.

Comment: No, I stated "Before anyone says, "DON'T DO THIS as it is really bad"." and then continued on with the reasons as to what I was doing and why.  I've seen many answers to similar questions on StackOverflow and others with such an unhelpful answer.  However, if you have suggestions as to how I could have worded that question, I would be interested in your comments.

Comment: I do not necessarily agree with people downvoting your question, I just observe that this is probably the case